# ValueError: Only call `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have just build my first model using Phyton, Keras and Tensorflow.

My model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))    
model.add(Activation('relu'))   
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))    
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))   

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))    
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Now i'm trying to compile it,

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',

              optimizer='rmsprop',

              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but i got this error:

> ValueError: Only call sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits with named
>   arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)

I can't seem to find what the problem is. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: what is you keras, tensorflow and python versions.?

Comment: keras 1.2.0
tensorflow 1.11.0
python 2.7.15

Comment: It was a bug in one of the earlier tensorflow versions. Updating them should fix the error.

Comment: Yay ! My problem is solved, thank you so much!